# OOP Trying to get propery of non-object via prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a user class that will have the registration & login, etc functions that can be used for my website. However, when I try and check if the username exists, I get the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\includes\user.class.php on line 22

I done a tonne of googling, and there was loads of information, but none of it was telling me why its giving me this error and how to fix it?
I have just started with OOP PHP, and prepared statements, so my code may be a bit wobbly.

This is the select function that I am using in my dbc class:

```
public function select($columns = array(), $table, $variables = '', $order = '') {
        // Are the required variables empty or equals null?
        if(empty($columns) || empty($table)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Set $order and $variables to false
        if($order == '' || $order == null) {
            $order = false;
        }else if($variables == '' || $variables == null) {
            $variables = false;
        }

        // Check if $columns is an array
        if(!is_array($columns)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Set $fields as an array
        $fields = array();
        // Individualise the array
        foreach($columns as $field) {
            $fields[] = $field;
        }

        // Sepeate all individuals with commas
        $fields = implode(', ', $fields);

        // Finalise the MySQLi query
        if($variables == false && $order == false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table";
        }else if($variables != false && $order == false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE $variables";
        }else if($variables == false && $order != false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table ORDER BY $order";
        }else if($variables != false && $order != false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE $variables ORDER BY $order";
        }

        // Prepare the query for executing
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

        // Execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // Get the results of the query
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        // Set the results to a variable
        while($row = ( is_object($result)) ? $result->fetch_assoc() : $result->fetch_object() ) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }

        // Return the results as array 0
        return $results[0];
    }
```

And this is the register function in the user class:

```
ublic function register($username, $password, $confirmpassword, $email, $firstname, $lastname) {
        if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($confirmpassword) || empty($email) || empty($firstname) || empty($lastname)) {
            return false;
        }

        if($password === $confirmpassword) {
            $dbc = new dbc();

            $hash = '_HG.g2Sxa.';
            $encryptpassword = md5(md5($hash . $password));

            $usernameQuery = $dbc->select(array('*'), 'users', 'username="' . $username .'"');
            $usernameCount = $usernameQuery->num_rows;

            if($usernameCount != 0) {
                echo 'Username already exists!';
            }

            $userdata = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $encryptpassword,
                'email' => $email,
                'firstname' => $firstname,
                'lastname' => $lastname,
                'status' => '1',
                'ip' => '127.0.0.1'
            );

            $dbc->insert('users', $userdata);
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I haven't had this problem before, as I only get it when attempting to count how many rows were found. But if I wasn't counting, then it would work absolutely great.

If anyone knows how I can fix this, I would highly appreciate it.
Also, if there are any problems with my code, please mention it so I can create improvements.

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: How do you think - who can guess on what line does this notice happen?

Comment: Oh sorry, thought I copied the whole line in. This is the full error code: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\includes\user.class.php on line 22 and line 22 is $usernameCount = $usernameQuery->num_rows;

Comment: What is in $dbc? Is the connection to the database established? Does _new dbc()_ not require some parameters like hostname, username, password, database name, etc.?

Comment: $dbc is the connnection to the database. It gets the parameters which are set as constants in the config. If the connection wasn't established I'd be getting errors from all over the place because I am calling from the database for themes, titles, etc.

Comment: What do you use to connect to the database? Is this PDO or mysqli?

Comment: I use MySQLi to connect to the database. I would also like to mention that after some troubleshooting, I have found out that the query is working. I print_r the query and it shows the correct results from the database:                                                                                         Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => test [password] => e012627b6a75087951baa300b6f8dc90 [email] => kieron.sutton99@outlook.com [firstname] => Kieron [lastname] => Sutton [status] => 1 [ip] => 127.0.0.2 )

Comment: However, I am still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
$usernameQuery = $dbc->select(array('*'), 'users', 'username="' . $username .'"');
$usernameCount = $usernameQuery->num_rows; // error is here
```

And it says `Trying to get property of non-object`, so the `$usernameCount` is not an object.

Possible reasons:

- Your `select` function returns `false` (it does in several places)
- The database query doesn't return any data, in this case there should be other notices like `Undefined variable: results`

Next, you do `$usernameQuery->num_rows`. I see no case at all where the `$usernameQuery` can have `num_rows` property. Your `select` returns the first data row in the best case and it will not have `num_rows` anyway.

And I actually don't see the point of such `select` implementation which reads all the data from the database and throws everything away except the first record.
If you need one record - use `limit 1` in your SQL.

Also you should use `bind_param` to bind parameters to your SQL. At the moment you just pass strings without parameters, so there is actually no use of `prepare`.

Actually there are many more issues with this code. You may try to post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask for review.